Software rendering - perspective correct texturemapping
I studied source code of an old game from the 90s and saw a function for perspective correct triangle texture mapping. In this function ymin and ymax - y1 and y2 - lines from to up draw triangle, and tptr - pointer to texture image 8 bit depth size is 256x256, phd_winptr is pointer to video memory (backbuffer).
Where can I read how this function works? I guess there are several kinds of perspective texturemapping method, how is this one called?
/******************************************************************************
 *                         TextureMapper
 *              Perspective Correction every 32 Pixels
 *****************************************************************************/
void    gtmap_persp32_fp( int ymin, int ymax, unsigned char *tptr )
{
    /* This version does 32 pixels at a time linearly, and adaptively double pixels for each 32 pixel span.
        Should only be used in 640x480 though */
    XBUF_PERSP_FP   *dataptr;
    unsigned char   *lineptr,*pixptr;
    float               ooz,uoz,voz,scale;
    float               oozadd32,uozadd32,vozadd32;
    int             start_g,add_g,add_g2;
    int             end_u,end_v;
    int             start_u,start_v;
    int             add_u,add_v;
    int             start_x,end_x;
    int             x;

    dataptr = ((XBUF_PERSP_FP *)xbuffer)+ymin;
    lineptr = (unsigned char*)phd_winptr + ( ymin*phd_scrwidth );
    for (ymax-=ymin; ymax>0; ymax--, dataptr++, lineptr+=phd_scrwidth)
    {
        start_x = dataptr->Xleft >> 16;
        end_x = dataptr->Xright >> 16;
        x = end_x - start_x;
        if (x <= 0)
            continue;
        
        if ( x>32 )
        {
            start_g = dataptr->Gleft;
            add_g = (dataptr->Gright-start_g) / x;
            add_g2 = add_g<<1;

            scale = 32.0f/x;
            uoz = dataptr->UOZleft;
            uozadd32 = (dataptr->UOZright-uoz) * scale;
            voz = dataptr->VOZleft;
            vozadd32 = (dataptr->VOZright-voz) * scale;
            ooz = dataptr->OOZleft;
            oozadd32 = (dataptr->OOZright-ooz) * scale;

            scale = 256.0f/ooz;
            end_u = (int)(uoz * scale);
            end_v = (int)(voz * scale);

            pixptr = lineptr + start_x;
        
            ooz += oozadd32;
            scale = 256.0f/ooz;
            
            for ( ; x>=32; x-=32)
            {
                start_u = end_u;
                uoz += uozadd32;
                end_u = (int)(uoz*scale);
                add_u = (end_u-start_u)>>5;

                start_v = end_v;
                voz += vozadd32;
                end_v = (int)(voz*scale);
                add_v = (end_v-start_v)>>5;

                // FP divide in parallel with the pixel drawing
                ooz += oozadd32;
                scale = 256.0f/ooz;

                if ((ABS(add_u) + ABS(add_v)) & SINGLE_MASK)
                {
                    // Single pixel it
                    *(pixptr) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+1) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+2) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+3) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+4) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+5) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+6) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+7) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+8) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+9) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+10) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+11) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+12) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+13) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+14) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+15) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_g += add_g;
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;

                    *(pixptr+16) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+17) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+18) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+19) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+20) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+21) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+22) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+23) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+24) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+25) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+26) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+27) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+28) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+29) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+30) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+31) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_g += add_g;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Double pixel it
                    add_u <<= 1;
                    add_v <<= 1;

                    *(pixptr) = *(pixptr+1) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+2) = *(pixptr+3) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+4) = *(pixptr+5) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+6) = *(pixptr+7) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+8) = *(pixptr+9) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+10) = *(pixptr+11) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+12) = *(pixptr+13) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+14) = *(pixptr+15) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+16) = *(pixptr+17) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+18) = *(pixptr+19) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+20) = *(pixptr+21) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+22) = *(pixptr+23) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+24) = *(pixptr+25) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+26) = *(pixptr+27) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+28) = *(pixptr+29) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+30) = *(pixptr+31) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_g += add_g2;
                }

                pixptr += 32;
            }

            if (!x)
                continue;

            // Do the odd bit at the end
            scale = 256.0f/dataptr->OOZright;

            start_u = end_u;
            end_u = (int)(dataptr->UOZright*scale);
            add_u = (end_u-start_u)/x;

            start_v = end_v;
            end_v = (int)(dataptr->VOZright*scale);
            add_v = (end_v-start_v)/x;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Special case for spans of 32 pixels or less */
            start_g = dataptr->Gleft;
            add_g = (dataptr->Gright-start_g) / x;

            scale = 256.0f/dataptr->OOZleft;
            start_u = (int)(dataptr->UOZleft * scale);
            start_v = (int)(dataptr->VOZleft * scale);

            scale = 256.0f/dataptr->OOZright;
            end_u = (int)(dataptr->UOZright * scale);
            end_v = (int)(dataptr->VOZright * scale);

            add_u = (end_u-start_u)/x;
            add_v = (end_v-start_v)/x;

            pixptr = lineptr + start_x;
        }

        /* Do bits of span less than 32 pixels */
        if ((ABS(add_u) + ABS(add_v)) & SINGLE_MASK)
        {
            /* Single pixel it */
            for ( ; x>1; x-=2, pixptr+=2)
            {
                pixptr[0] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
                start_u += add_u;
                start_v += add_v;
                start_g += add_g;
                pixptr[1] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
                start_u += add_u;
                start_v += add_v;
                start_g += add_g;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Double pixel it */
            add_u <<= 1;
            add_v <<= 1;
            add_g2 = add_g<<1;

            for ( ; x>1; x-=2, pixptr+=2)
            {
                pixptr[0] = pixptr[1] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
                start_u += add_u;
                start_v += add_v;
                start_g += add_g2;
            }
        }

        if (x)
            pixptr[0] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
    }
}

```


Might find a bigger audience at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

@black4 What game is this code from? Was the code obtained legally (e.g. from an official source release from the developer or current rights-holder?)

A quick search on the function name turned up https://github.com/Arsunt/TR2Main/blob/master/TR2_progress.txt so maybe it's Tomb Raider code?

Old hardware did not have floating point units and thus handling floats was SLOW!!! The code given reduced the amount of floating point work by using floats only to get the non linear "Perspective" texture position for every 32 pixel across (x direction). The 32 pixel blocks are scanned linearly using Fixed Point. Eg the lookup ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) is same as v * 256 + u with the high 16 bits of the 32bit Ints representing whole units. Do you have a screenshot of a render as this would have some strange artifacts.

So you mean that 32 pixels in a row use affine texture mapping, and every 32 pixels use perspective texture mapping? What is depthq_table used for - is it a color table?

@Blindman67 that looks like the start of a good answer you could post below, giving you more room and better formatting options than a comment.

@black4 Yes and depthq_table looks like a texture map. Without seeing the data my guess is that the display and texture maps are using index pallet lookup (256 color display) where the pixel value is used to index into an RGB table  to determine the pixel color. Why it is called depthq_table is unknown to me.

@DMGregory Too much guess work to make a good answer in my book.
